# I'm high in the sky, but also in the ground. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

Something I came up with real quick...

> I'm high in the sky
>   But I'm also in the ground
>   I can exist in two dimensions
>   But it is in three, where I am also found
>
> Sometimes I level the world around me
>  
>   Or maybe I'm at a slant
>   Other times I'm a vessel-
>   I'm also the name of a certain type of plant

That should be enough, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is:

> plane

because:

I'm high in the sky

> airplanes can be found in the sky

But I'm also in the ground

> like crystal "Lattice plane"

I can exist in two dimensions
But it is in three, where I am also found

> both in 2d and 3d there are planes

Sometimes I level the world around me
Or maybe I'm at a slant

> planes can be either horizontal or slant

Other times I'm a vessel-

> this could refer to planing - the mode of operation for a waterborne craft

I'm also the name of a certain type of plant

> "Platanus", a genus of trees with the common name "plane"

Comment: I guess it was a bit too easy :)

Comment: @michal Don't count on it. Sometimes it is just matter of luck and state of mind ;)

Comment: If I could just add one thing- The explanation for line 2 is a little bit off. I was referring to a tree's roots being in the ground.

Comment: @michal Can you explain about tree's roots? I never met such use of "plane"...

Comment: You said yourself that `"Platanus", a genus of trees` . I'm simply referring to this tree, which has roots in the ground. (I'm referring to the tree being in the ground.)